# How to send attribute from Database to dJ to make Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

/*
    * DynamicJasper: A library for creating reports dynamically by specifying
    * columns, groups, styles, etc. at runtime. It also saves a lot of development
    * time in many cases! (http://sourceforge.net/projects/dynamicjasper)
    *
    * Copyright (C) 2008  FDV Solutions (http://www.fdvsolutions.com)
    *
    * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
    * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   *
   * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   *
   * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
   *
   * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   *
   * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   *
   * Lesser General Public License for more details.
   *
   * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
   *
   * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
   *
   *
   */

```
    package ar.com.fdvs.dj.test;

    import java.sql.*;

   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.util.Date;
   import java.util.Locale;

  import net.sf.jasperreports.view.*;
  import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.AutoText;
  import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.DynamicReport;
  import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.Style;
  import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.FastReportBuilder;
  import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.StyleBuilder;
  import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Font;
  import ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DJConstants;
 // import ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.*;
  public class Main extends BaseDjReportTest {
```

public DynamicReport buildReport() throws Exception {
               // Connection C = new Connection();
               // C.Con();
            CConnection C= new CConnection();
            C.Connection();
            Statement stmt;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM student";
            stmt = C.Con().createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
            String res= "";

```
FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();

drb.setQuery(SQL, DJConstants.QUERY_LANGUAGE_SQL);
           while (rs.next()){
                 res= rs.getString("Name");
            **drb.addColumn("Name","Name", String.class.getName(),30);**
          //  drb.addc
           }
 //.addColumn("Branch", "branch", String.class.getName(),30)

  // .addColumn("Item", "item", String.class.getName(),50)
// .addColumn("Item Code", "id", Long.class.getName(),30,true)
// .addColumn("Quantity", "quantity", Long.class.getName(),60,true)
// .addColumn("Amount", "amount", Float.class.getName(),70,true)
drb.addGroups(2);
                    DynamicReport sa =drb.build();

 drb.setSubtitle("This report was generated at " + new Date())
 .setTemplateFile("templates/TemplateReportTest.jrxml")

                    .setUseFullPageWidth(true);


Style atStyle = new                    StyleBuilder(true).setFont(Font.COMIC_SANS_SMALL).setTextColor(Color.red).build();
Style atStyle2 = new StyleBuilder(true).setFont(new Font(9, Font._FONT_TIMES_NEW_ROMAN, false, true, false)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE).build();

/***
* Adding many autotexts in the same position (header/footer and aligment) makes them to be one on top of the other
 */
//First add in the FOOTER
drb.addAutoText(AutoText.AUTOTEXT_PAGE_X, AutoText.POSITION_HEADER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,200,40, atStyle);
drb.addAutoText("Autotext below Page counter", AutoText.POSITION_FOOTER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_LEFT);

//Note the styled text: <b>msimone</b>, valid tags are: <b>, <i> and <u>
drb.addAutoText("Created by <b>msimone</b>", AutoText.POSITION_FOOTER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_RIGHT,200);
drb.addAutoText(AutoText.AUTOTEXT_PAGE_X_SLASH_Y, AutoText.POSITION_FOOTER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_RIGHT,30,30,atStyle2);

drb.addAutoText(AutoText.AUTOTEXT_CREATED_ON, AutoText.POSITION_FOOTER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,AutoText.PATTERN_DATE_DATE_TIME);

//Now in HEADER
drb.addAutoText(AutoText.AUTOTEXT_PAGE_X_OF_Y, AutoText.POSITION_HEADER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,100,40);
drb.addAutoText("Autotext at top-left", AutoText.POSITION_HEADER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,200);

drb.addAutoText("Autotext at top-left (2)", AutoText.POSITION_HEADER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,200);
drb.addAutoText("Autotext at top-center", AutoText.POSITION_HEADER, AutoText.ALIGNMENT_CENTER,200,atStyle);
```

// DynamicReport dr = drb.build();

```
//i18N, you can set a Locale, different tha n the default in the VM
drb.setReportLocale(new Locale("es","AR"));
drb.setReportLocale(new Locale("pt","BR"));
drb.setReportLocale(new Locale("fr","FR"));

return sa;
```

}

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    **Main test = new Main();
   test.testReport();**
     JasperViewer.viewReport(test.jp);
            JasperDesignViewer.viewReportDesign(test.jr);
  //JasperDesignViewer.viewReportDesign(DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(test.dr, test.getLayoutManager(),new HashMap()));
}
```

}

Writing this code i m getting following exception and i really cant figure out the reason

Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : varchar at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:818)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:782)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1448)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:108)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:923)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:85)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
        at ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.BaseDjReportTest.testReport(BaseDjReportTest.java:93)
        at ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.Main.main(Main.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'varchar' on class 'class ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.domain.Product'
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1322)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:770)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
        ... 12 more
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 3):

You may be aware of this already, but it appears that somewhere, the code is trying to access a property called "varchar" on the Product object:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'varchar' on class 'class ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.domain.Product' at .....

I don't see where this is happening in your example. It may be that there is a place where name is expected and you are instead passing in type. Or somewhere in your configuration, you've got name and type switched around, so it's looking for a field named "varchar". Does that make sense?

In general, I find that the "Caused by" portion of the error log is the most informative.